# MySQL union all columns

Tags: mysql, sql, join, union

I have a mysql table for cases. It has product name for each product there can be multiple records with different statuses.

MySQL Fiddler : [SQL Fiddler Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/953f7/2)

```
SELECT 
product , count(*) as totalopen
FROM cases
where status='OPEN'
group by product
union all
SELECT 
product , count(*) as totalclosed
FROM cases
where status='CLOSED'
group by product
```

It is giving me result as [image: Fiddler result]

But I want result as
[image]

What exactly I am missing in query. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What's the expected result if you add DEF, OPEN to your table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code via using `Inner Join`:

```
Select a.product, totalopen , totalclosed
from (
SELECT 
product , count(*) as totalopen
FROM cases
where status='OPEN'
group by product ) a
inner join (
SELECT 
product ,count(*) as totalclosed
FROM cases
where status='CLOSED'
group by product ) b
on a.product = b.product.
```

**Updated:-**

For the products that has only one record, so its status has only `CLOSED` or `OPEN` use `Full Outer Join` instead of `inner join` as next:-

```
Select isnull(a.product,b.product) product, isnull(totalopen,0) totalopen , isnull(totalclosed,0) totalclosed
from (
SELECT 
product , count(*) as totalopen
FROM cases
where status='OPEN'
group by product ) a
full outer join (
SELECT 
product ,count(*) as totalclosed
FROM cases
where status='CLOSED'
group by product ) b
on a.product = b.product
```

Comment: Will not return a product with only status open (or only status closed.)

Comment: @jarlh that is right, I wrote the code depends on the input of data, however the answer has updated for covering your case. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `case` expressions to conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT product,
       count(case when status='OPEN' then 1 end) as totalopen,
       count(case when status='CLOSED' then 1 end) as totalclosed
FROM cases
where status in ('OPEN', 'CLOSED')
group by product
```

If you want to include products with only other status (e.g. pending), remove the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Can you explain what is purpose of "then 1" ?

Comment: `count()` counts non-null values. The `1` there is just a non-null value. No `else` value means NULL, and not counted.

Comment: @Michail Michailidis, thanks for correcting the typo!

Answer (score 0):

Use `case` expression and count the relevant ones.

```
SELECT 
product ,
count(case when status = 'OPEN' then 1 end) as totalopen,
count(case when status = 'CLOSED' then 1 end) as totalclosed
FROM cases
group by product;
```

It uses the fact that

```
COUNT(1) = 1
COUNT(NULL) = 0
```

and

```
case when 1 = 1 then 1 end -- return 1
case when 1 = 2 then 1 end -- return null
```

Comment: Those are case expressions, not case statements.

Comment: @jarlh Fixed. Thanks